# Is migration file must in Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I started my project with sequeliz-cli by running init command.

but i deleted the migrations and seeder folder. and started creating the models.

i need to first create a db in workbench, and then ran db.sync() from sequelize, which created the tables in db. Its running kind of fine.

can we complete the whole project without using migrate and deploy it on production env, will not using migrate disadvantageous??

Comment: What disadnvantages of migrations do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrations help you to use different versions of your app and DB in different production environments and change your DB structure as long as to add some initial data precisely.

**sync** method would be dangerous in such scenarios with different versions in a situation when you run a newer version of your app on an older DB occasionally.

If you have a simple DB structure that won't change or will be the same on all prods then you can use **sync**.